# Multiple inheritance issues, non-cooperative class?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to create something with multiple inheritance and having a difficult time getting it to work.  I have a diagram showing what I am trying to do.  I think I have to use an adapter class based on some of the research I've done with non-cooperative classes.  Here is my code and the diagram.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
class SwapClient(object):
    def __init__(self, slippage):
        self.slippage = slippage
    def add_liquidity(self):
        print("Add liquidity")

class WaultSwapClient(SwapClient):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.exchange_name = 'waultswap'
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class BSCClient:
    def __init__(self, testnet, gas_price, gas_buffer, *args, **kwargs):
        self.testnet = testnet
        self.gas_price = gas_price
        self.gas_buffer = gas_buffer
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class WaultSwapBSCClient(BSCClient, WaultSwapClient):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def claim_(self, pid):
        print("Claim rewards")

sc = WaultSwapBSCClient(True, 5, 1, 0.01)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: Why are you passing `self` to all your `super().__init__` calls?

Comment: And what's the question supposed to be? You've posted a picture and some code, but not actually asked a question for us to answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate *having a difficult time getting it to work*?

Comment: In the examples I saw, it seemed like self was being passed in the inits.

Comment: As far as my question, what am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I actually think I fixed it thanks to @user2357112.  I removed self from the super calls which made it work.

```
class SwapClient(object):
    def __init__(self, slippage):
        self.slippage = slippage
    def add_liquidity(self):
        print("Add liquidity")

class WaultSwapClient(SwapClient):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.exchange_name = 'waultswap'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BSCClient:
    def __init__(self, testnet, gas_price, gas_buffer, *args, **kwargs):
        self.testnet = testnet
        self.gas_price = gas_price
        self.gas_buffer = gas_buffer
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class WaultSwapBSCClient(BSCClient, WaultSwapClient):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def claim_(self, pid):
        print("Claim rewards")

sc = WaultSwapBSCClient(True, 5, 1, 0.01)
```